# A thread to request questions be made community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I'm putting this up for people to request that questions be made community wiki.

Comment: Not to say this is a bad idea, but sometimes people say that a question should be wikified when it really should be closed. But converting to CW doesn't make an inappropriate question okay. The true use cases for wikification are very rare these days - on Physics (just because that's the site I'm most active on) I don't think we've made anything CW in weeks. I just want to make sure people don't get carried away and start using this thread for the wrong purposes.

Answer (score 5):

To add to *and* underscore @DavidZaslavsky's point, there's been an increasing number of suggestions to wikify posts. Before suggesting that something should be made Community Wiki (CW), please read [this blog post by Grace Note](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

The rough guideline given by Grace Note is that no more than **one in one hundred questions** should be CW. As of February 6, 2012, we have roughly 300 questions, so no more than 3 questions should be CW.

It also seems like if a post is valuable, it probably doesn't need to be CW. In the rare case where people ask for lists of references, such as @Dan's first suggestion for a CW question, CW might be acceptable as long as some sort of commentary accompanies each reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think these should probably be made community wiki:

[Which journals should I read to keep up on advances in solving PDEs numerically?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1116/81)

[What core skills should every computational scientist have?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1148/81)

Comment: I've made both of those questions community wiki.

Comment: Update: I closed the second question on your list.

Comment: I think it probably needed to be closed.

Comment: @Geoff Oxberry: After reading the post you linked, I'm starting to thinkg you should probably close mine (the first one) as well.

Comment: Probably. I'll close it and see what people say.